# How to edit/send a previously sent gmail message as a new one on Android?

Tags: gmail, email, imap

Something well known to be unsupported on the official gmail.com website and official app.

The typical answer in that case, is go on Microsoft Windows to install an imap client like Thunderbird which has such feature. **But how to do it if you have only access to an android devices?**

I tried the beta version of k9 which is to be rebranded as Thunderbird for Android and it does support copying sent messages but not across mailboxes/imap account whereas Google doesn’t support copying emails to a the Drafts folder (you normally have to use a client which support send a message as new directly or put the message in the drafts folder of an other imap account which isn’t Google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FairEmail](https://github.com/M66B/FairEmail/blob/master/FAQ.md#user-content-faq6) supports it. You can download it from [Github release page](https://github.com/M66B/FairEmail/releases/), or  on Play Store (available in some countries only). I've been using FairEmail ever since it was released and it has tons of amazing features (I am not affiliated with it, just promoting a great product).

Though the XDA thread is closed, development is ongoing with an update once a week on average. He is the one who's developed Net guard, XPrivacy and XPrivacyLua.

On top of every message there is a configurable set of actions. Tap the three dot menu (second on left) and follow the screenshots

[image]

Select *edit as new*

[image]

You can change the from(any mail client configured in FairEmail) /to mail ID, subject, header or text and send it.

[image]

You can read the Github (linked in first Para) for other features of the app.